# Different result types for @-parameters between MySQL 5.0 and 5.1

Tags: mysql, types

I use the following statement as an example:

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect( '127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass' );
  mysql_query('SET @a = "test";', $link);
  $r = mysql_query('SELECT @a;', $link);
  echo mysql_field_type($r,0);
?>
```

When I execute this on MySQL 5.0 the output is "string".
When I execute this on MySQL 5.1 the output is "blob".

Is this a bug? Or is there a setting to change this behavior? My extarnal applications are expecting a string and now fail with this new result type. Hopefully someone can help me with this one.

Comment: According to the documentation this is not so, strange.

Comment: Actually it is:
On http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html they mention If the value of a user variable is selected in a result set, it is returned to the client as a string. So not a blob as it is at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer as to why, but a workaround

```
$r = mysql_query('SELECT CAST(@a AS VARCHAR(255)) as outcome;', $link);
```

According to the 5.0 docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

> If the value of a user variable is selected in a result set, it is returned to the client as a string.

The 5.1, 5.5 and 5.6 docs say exactly the same.

Comment: Tnx for your workaround.
I use Delphi as a client so this would be a pretty big workaround. Would be better if there was a fix.

Comment: @Marco, both Delphi as php accept SQL, so what's the problem with changing the SQL? Just use a TQuery in Delphi instead of a TTable.